# Open Page using Phantomjs (.js file)

Tags: javascript, browser, phantomjs

I am new using Phantomjs, and I got the content from a website that I want. Now I want to pass the content into my website (http://test123.com).  So what I want to do is, I want to open my website into a new tab in browser. However, I put the code below to test.js file and call it using `phantomjs test.js` but it didnt work.

```
var win = window.open("http://test123.com");
```

Anyone know how can I open a new tab in a browser using phantomjs? what should I put in my .js file ?

Comment: Completely off topic, i would suggest you to use https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer instead of phantomjs because of the nicer api and it internally using a real chrome browser

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't really have tabs. But that doesn't matter because you don't need them. Your REAL question should be "How do I pass the content into my website".

Comment: So what should I use to do that? I want to create external script to pass get the content from another website into my website.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    var win = window.open("http://test123.com", "_blank");
```

Comment: Is that for PhantomJS? Could you please provide a minimal working PhantomJS script using this line?